# My iMac Messages merges two other household members

Tags: imac, messages

My iMac, but not my iphone, merges messages to/from my wife and daughter, who have different iphone numbers and emails but share the same landline and street address.  How can I unscramble this? It's impossible to know which of them I am contacting or is contacting me..

Comment: Do you share your Mac account with your wife and daughter or do you all have seperate Mac accounts?

Comment: No, we all have separate accounts.  My wife has two, mysteriously (work and home, I think) and this has caused problems in the past...